# Changing text in a file with Random text Python

Tags: python, random, replace

I am learning Python. I am trying this code to read a file with some text in it (say three or four long paragraphs), and change/replace the text in completely new random text of the same length. Is it possible?

Also, can we read multiple files at once and randomly change the text in each file?

The code that I am using is able to read the file and copy the same text into another file. But I do not know how to achieve my objective.

```
def replacetext(search_text, replace_text):
with FileInput("SampleFile.txt", inplace=True,
            backup='.bak') as f:

    for line in f:
        print(line.replace(search_text,replace_text), end='')

return "Text replaced"
search_text = "dummy"

replace_text = "replaced"
print(replacetext(search_text, replace_text))
```

Comment: If you replace 'dummy' with 'replaced' then your objective of maintaining the same length isn't going to work. Can you say more about 'random' text? What do you really mean by that?

Comment: What I meant from the random text is that.... for example, one of my files contained text like this  "Baba Black sheep have you any wool, Yes, sir, Yes sir, three bags full", then it is replaced with the randomly generated text of the same length such as "Man is fond of adventures. His spirit of inquiry compells him to know more about the world around him"

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you provided in the comments (eventhough your strings wheren not of equal length).

```py
import random

text1 = "Baba Black sheep have you any wool, Yes, sir, Yes sir, three bags full."
text2 = "Man is fond of adventures. His spirit of inquiry compells him to know more about the world around him"

# OR IF YOU WANT TO READ FROM FILES
with open('sample1.txt') as f:
    text1 = f.read()

with open('sample2.txt') as f:
    text2 = f.read()

print(text1)
# Baba Black sheep have you any wool, Yes, sir, Yes sir, three bags full.

text1 = text1.split()
text2 = text2.split()

length = min(len(text1), len(text2))
for _ in range(5):
    i = random.randrange(length)
    text1[i] = text2[i]

text1 = ' '.join(text1)
print(text1)
# Man Black fond have you any wool, Yes, sir, compells him three bags full.
```

note: The `5` in `for _ in range(5)` specifies how many changes to make.

The real number could also be less than that as it may pick the same number more than once.